# NuxtJs: how to add a module to modules array in nuxt.config.js programtically?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to add `@nuxtjs/recaptcha` module based on my env variable. I have a boolean variable in my `publicRuntimeConfig` block, I need to check this variable when Nuxt boots up and add the `@nuxtjs/recaptcha` module if its true.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

I am currently doing like this:

```js
// check if isCaptchaEnabled is true.
// if true push it to the modules array.
if (config.publicRuntimeConfig.isCaptchaEnabled) {
  config.modules.push('@nuxtjs/recaptcha')
}
```

It is working but I think there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: `process.env.IS_CAPTCHA_ENABLED === 'true' && '@nuxtjs/recaptcha',` may be working if written directly into `modules`.

Comment: is there anyway we could it with a custom module or plugin ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that into a plugin? Also, what do you call "custom module"? One that you'll create?

Comment: i am not sure about the plugin, if we can do it there, but i saw ngrok example which pushes objects to nuxt config, can we do that with a custom module (i will create that , basically a wrapper for the orignal module i want to add dynamically)